# Override div's overflow:hidden

Tags: html, css

I need to bring Facebook's like button's description out of div.
Here is the link:

http://jsfiddle.net/HmzCh/2/

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="fblike">
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.google.com?v2&amp;t=%27Facebook%27" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false"></div><br/>
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.google.com?v3&amp;t=%27Facebook%27" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false"></div><br/>
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.google.com?v4&amp;t=%27Facebook%27" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false"></div><br/>
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.google.com?v5&amp;t=%27Facebook%27" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false"></div><br/>
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.google.com?v6&amp;t=%27Facebook%27" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false"></div><br/>
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.google.com?v7&amp;t=%27Facebook%27" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false"></div><br/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper2" >
     abc defghi abc defghi abc defghi abc defghi abc defghi abc defghi abc defghi abc defghi abc defghi abc defghi abc defghi abc defghi abc defghi abc defghi abc defghi abc defghi abc defghi abc defghi abc defghi abc defghi abc defghi abc defghi abc defghi abc defghi 
</div>
```

1. Wrapper class has to have overflow:hidden
2. Facebook's like buttons should stay at the provided position.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want this: http://jsfiddle.net/HmzCh/3/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a typo?

**position: bsolute;** 
should be 
**position: absolute;**